# How do I convert this Object's format?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
OBJECT
    description ["Good stuff", "Bad stuff"]
    months_left ["12", "24"]
```

to

```
OBJECT
    description[0][0] = "Good stuff"
    months_left[0][1] = "12"
    description[1][0] = "Bad stuff"
    months_left[1][1] = "24"
```

Thank u!

Comment: I didn't do it, but I'm wondering - is your last line accurate?  It might also be helpful to know why as this is a pretty odd request.

Comment: I'm trying to convert an object from 1 format to another. My mind was stuck in a for loop and thought the community here might throw in a break.. actually "pimvdb"'s answer below gave me the hint to solve it.

Comment: Ahh, then don't be discouraged by the down vote.  We like to up vote questions that will be helpful to others as well as the original poster.  In this case, your question was perfect for your own purposes, but vague enough not to be useful to others.  The down vote indicates that it's not very valuable - but people may still answer it and help you (which is what happened!).  Make sense?  Granted, it may have been a bit much in this case, but I can see where they were coming from.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clearing it up jbrookover. I'll add more detail next time so it's clearer to other folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like...

```
for(var i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
    description[i] = [description[i]];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works for the last line as it would put 24 in `months_left[1][0]` if you used it in the same manner.  Of course, the question is possibly mistaken.

Comment: Awesome, this lead me to my answer. Wasn't exact what I needed but definitely in the right direction. I had to do nested for each loops to get it. Thanks dude.

Comment: Oh I see, the indexes made me a little dizzy. Great you solved the problem nevertheless.